# jQuery: Hide a div. After clicking a button show that div and hide another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

**My concept is this:**
There is `div-1` and `div-2`. `div-2` will be hidden and the `div-1` will be shown. There is a `button` in the shown `div-1`. After clicking the `button` the `div-1` will be hidden and the `div-2` will be shown.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div id="report-medicine">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h3>REPORT A SUSPICIOUS MEDICINE</h3>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group medicine-information">
                        <textarea type="text" class="" placeholder="Tell Us About The Fake Medicine..."></textarea>
                        <button class="btn">Next</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="user-information">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Report</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".user-information").hide();
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(".medicine-information").hide()
        $(".user-information").show()
    });
});
</script>
```

But the code isn't working :/ Please help me by correcting the code.

Comment: have you included jquery link?

Comment: Yeah, at the bottom of the body

Comment: where is html for `medicine-inforamtion` can you share it too

Comment: please check my answer it will work

Comment: In future, to help those who answer your question, please be specific about what's wrong or what doesn't work in your code .. I don't think many understood that the form was being submitted when pressing "Next", but you would have seen that.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has a toggle method built in.  Basically, set the div you want hidden first to 'display: none;' and then toggle both between visible and hidden on the button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#div1").toggle();
    $("#div2").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#div1 {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#div2 {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="hidden">
    <p>World!</p>
  </div>
  <button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Using a toggle doesn't explain why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your form will submit automatically if you use `<button>` without setting an explicit type.

A simple fix:

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Next</button>
```

This will cause the button to have no default behaviour, so you can handle the click event without having to worry that the form will submit. [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhseLbf9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Put jquery link just above your script

Please replace this:-

```
<button class="btn">Next</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Report</button>
```

with:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Next</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Report</button>
```

So try this code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="report-medicine">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h3>REPORT A SUSPICIOUS MEDICINE</h3>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group medicine-information">
                        <textarea type="text" class="" placeholder="Tell Us About The Fake Medicine..."></textarea>
                        <button type="button" class="btn">Next</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="user-information">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn">Report</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".user-information").hide();
            $(".btn").click(function () {
                $(".medicine-information").hide()
                $(".user-information").show()
            });
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buttons should be in a form.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some typos. For a quick fix.

Replace

```
  $("medicine-inforamtion").hide();
   $(".user-information").show();
```

With

```
   $(".medicine-information").hide();
   $(".user-information").show();
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".user-information").hide();
    $(".btn").click(function(){
     $(".medicine-information").hide()
        $(".user-information").show()
    });
});`
Still not working

Comment: You need to fix the spelling of "medicine-inforamtion" in your html too.

Comment: Semicolons are optional.

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: If you set us up with the fiddle I'll be happy to take a look. And although semi colons are optional if there's a line break, I believe they're best practice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please use:-

```
$(".medicine-inforamtion").hide();
```

1. class name is different
2. use "."  in selector to select an class.

Answer (score 0):

you use form action in first div.. so the page get refreshed. and you got the same page with textarea.try to use Ajax `Onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will only work on the first click (one div will be hidden the other shown).  But clicks after that will just continue to set the already hidden div to hidden and shown will continue to be shown.  Fortunately jquery has a way to show if hidden and hide if shown.  Toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".user-information").hide();
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(".medicine-information").toggle()
        $(".user-information").toggle()
    });
});
```

Comment: If you do this, before the form is submitted it will show the first div again.